# how to recover when /etc has been deleted on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, etc

I have accidentally deleted `/etc`. 
Does anybody knows how to recover from such a situation ? 
At least I can use ssh while the server is in rescue mode (dedicated server from ovh.com). 
I could already mount / and /home. 
Now I need to recover /etc content and reinstall correctly all my stuff. 
I am using virtual-box for this ad I'll try to copy /etc from the virtual box to the server. 
May be I will need to make a clean install from scratch ?

Comment: Restore from backups?

Comment: I don't have backup of /etc

Comment: *"Now I need to recover /etc content"* - that's just plain data recovery. There's no undelete, unless you did this in a desktop environment with a file manager with support for a "trash" to recover from.

Comment: Unfortunately it is headless, so only via ssh...

Answer (score 2):

In leiu of restoring from backup, the easiest way is going to be to just back up /home and reinstall. Next time you can just job the entire VirtualBox file to back it up.

Comment: yes that's what I currently doing finally.

Comment: Actually without a backup of /etc, the only way I found is, before a complete re-install, to try to backup as much as possible data.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments and suggestions ! Have a nice day.